# Permission denied for window type 2002 & 2038

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-permissions

I'm showing a service overly window and it's working properly with most of my users, however I find these errors on Crashlytics

Older devices (Android 7 and below)

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.app.name.mainService: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@43108e0 -- permission denied for window type 2002
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService + 3172(ActivityThread.java:3172)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1550(ActivityThread.java:1550)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 102(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop + 154(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6077(ActivityThread.java:6077)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 865(ZygoteInit.java:865)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 755(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Newer devices (Especially Galaxy S8 Android 9.0)

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.app.name.mainService: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@df3ca8f -- permission denied for window type 2038
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService + 3768(ActivityThread.java:3768)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400 + 237(ActivityThread.java:237)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1801(ActivityThread.java:1801)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 106(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop + 214(Looper.java:214)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 7050(ActivityThread.java:7050)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 493(RuntimeInit.java:493)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 965(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

My code I'm using is

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,

                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN |
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SPLIT_TOUCH |
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        } else {
            params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,

                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN |
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SPLIT_TOUCH |
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        }

        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        if (mWindowManager != null) {
            mWindowManager.addView(serviceRootView, params);
        }
```

I'm also making sure that Draw permission is granted and manifest file has permission for

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

And I searched a lot on other questions, all suggested the above solution but it is not helpful as the crash still occurs!

Comment: Can you please add full error ?

Comment: There's no need to create a overlay window in service just launch a activity from service take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57302001/how-to-overlay-a-layout-on-lock-screen-when-in-devices-running-oreo-and-pie

Comment: @PratikSatani I've updated the question

Comment: using above solution you can easily launch any window or screen over your screen without need of any permissions

Comment: Sorry but for some reasons I don't want to display an activity.

Comment: My question is not related to Lockscreens. I don't know why you keep referring to such posts

Comment: What is your targeted level in the project ?

Comment: targetSdkVersion 26

Comment: @MoDev hey, have you found the solution?